# Mysql search of large document library

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search

I was using PHP to search for a pool of text files and pull small lines of text using strpos() from that matched a search string. This proved to work on small scale, but not at all on a large scale.

I've been looking at Mysql's fulltext search, but it seems to not work particularly well for the kind of nitpicky thing I want (e.g. search for every instance of the word "school" in a series of documents then pull the results of those searches). And some of the documents are very long.

I could try using the mysql fulltext search to pull the relevant documents, then have php go through them and find each occurrence of a string... 
-- The kind of search I want is really dumb in this way, and not enlightened at all.

(Edit)
So the question is: Can I use Mysql to pull all matching strings from a cell like I can with strpos() in php, or if the documents (+50 pages each) are rather long? And then should I?

Comment: Have you looked at using something like [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)?

Comment: So you think I'd need to go more heavy duty and install a search framework?

Answer (score 0):

The two options for search framework are [Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) and [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

Both are built on top of lucene.